# How come the texnansi-encoding didn't work for the Symbol-font?

Tags: fonts, postscript

I've been installing PostScript Type 1 fonts in TeXLive, where I've used the texnansi encoding. Everything worked very well with every PS Type 1 font I tried, except when I came to the Symbol font, where a font display printout showed absolutely nothing but empty slots. Should I have used another encoding? At least I thought I should have seen something.
The font printout was done by means of the \char command, i.e. \char0  \char1  \char2  .  .  . \char255. I realize that the Symbol font is already there by default. But I nevertheless thought it might be valuable to learn how to install a slightly different Symbol font.

Comment: Well in symbol fonts glyphs have a tendency to have other names then the glyphs in text fonts. So the texnansi-encoding won't work with them. But why use an encoding at all?

Comment: @Ulrike Great idea. It occurred to me too that I shouldn't use any encodement. It may sound odd, but I only know how to do it by using encodement via the map-file. The no-encodement solution is probably so simple that it cannot easily be found as an explicit statement. And now I am hoping that you will tell me how :-)

Comment: Well if you look in pdftex.map you will see quite a lot fonts loaded without encoding. E.g. `cmr10 CMR10 <cmr10.pfb`

Comment: Okay, I got it !  The map entry is  psyr StandardSymL <usyr.pfb

Comment: The Font Installation Guide has a section on doing this, too. You might find it useful - at least worth a look. Note that there are times when it does make sense to use an encoding even with symbol fonts. One is if you wish to use a truetype symbol font directly with pdfTeX.